# how to run or install a *.jar file in windows?

Tags: java, installation, jar, executable-jar

I have downloaded `jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar` but I don't know how to install or run the file.

If I double click on it, it opens in `winrar`. I tried installing through command prompt, but I got the following errors:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ccuser\Desktop\manoj>java -jar jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/izforge/izpack/installer/Installer (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Here is something useful:  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/4144970

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `UnsupportedClassVersionError` means that you are probably using (installed) an older version of Java as used to create the JAR.
Go to [java.sun.com page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), download and install a newer JRE (Java Runtime Environment).
if you want/need to develop with Java, you will need the JDK which includes the JRE.

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried (from a command line)

`java -jar jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar`

or double clicking it with the mouse ?

Found [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jbpm/209-jbpm-4-tutorial-installation.html) and [this](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v3/gpd/installation.html) by googling.

Hope it helps

Comment: if i double click it, it is opening in winrar!. wrong file association, i guess.

Comment: A jar file equivilent to a zip file, which is why winrar will have opened it, the association is not *wrong* per se, just in this case you want to execute the code within the jar

Comment: @brainless Try looking at the first link I posted.

Comment: Running with the -jar option in a console opened as admin worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

To run usually click and it should run, that is if you have java installed. If not get java from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
Sorry thought it was more general open a command prompt and type `java -jar jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar`

Answer (score 1):

If double-clicking on it brings up WinRAR, you need to change the program you are running it with.  You can right-click on it and click "Open with".  Java should be listed in there.

However, you must first upgrade your Java version to be compatible with that JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a command prompt and type `java -jar jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar`

Comment: How does that differ from @Tom's earlier answer?